# Running Protractor tests on Browserstack Automate

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, browserstack

I'm developing an AngularJS app and want to do end-2-end testing with Protractor. I would like to benefit from the suite of test browsers available at Browserstack and run the tests on Browserstack Automate instead of a local Selenium server.

How do I set up a system to run these tests?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Protractor from [version 3.0.0](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/1a8bb5357ccc254ce9453972fee8521efbeb0a4d/CHANGELOG.md#features) onwards has added [inbuilt support](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/7015010188dfb70c1e49e4f2eae19d5ba1126b34) for BrowserStack.

You simply need to add the following two parameters in your `conf.js` to launch the test on BrowserStack:

```
browserstackUser: '<username>'
browserstackKey: '<automate-key>'
```

Your username and automate key can be found [here](https://www.browserstack.com/accounts/automate), after you have logged in to your account.

Hence, lets say you wish to run your test on **Chrome 50 / OS X Yosemite**, your `conf.js` should look something like this:

```
exports.config = {
  specs: ['spec.js'],

  browserstackUser: '<username>',
  browserstackKey: '<automate-key>',

  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'Chrome',
    browser_version: '50.0',
    os: 'OS X',
    os_version: 'Yosemite'
  },    
};
```

If you wish to run tests in **parallel on different browser and OS combinations**, you can use the `multiCapabilities` as given below:

```
exports.config = {
  specs: ['spec.js'],

  browserstackUser: '<username>',
  browserstackKey: '<automate-key>',

  multiCapabilities: [
    {
        browserName: 'Safari',
        browser_version: '8.0',
        os: 'OS X',
        os_version: 'Yosemite'
    },
    {
       browserName: 'Firefox',
       browser_version: '30.0',
       os: 'Windows',
       os_version: '7'
    },
    {
       browserName: 'iPhone',
       platform: 'MAC',
       device: 'iPhone 5S'
    }
  ]
};
```

Some helpful links:

1. [Code Generator](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/node#setting-os-and-browser) - Helps you configure the capabilities to test on different various browser and OS combinations especially mobile devices.
2. Sample [Github project](https://github.com/browserstack/protractor-browserstack/tree/protractor_3_0) for Protractor-BrowserStack - This should help you get started.

Comment: How to enable local testing?

Comment: 2 steps:
a) Download the binaries [here](https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing#command-line) and execute them using the following command `BrowserstackLocal.exe <automate-key>`
b) Add the capability `'browserstack.local' : true` to your config file

Comment: Alternatively you can also use this Node module - https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserstack-local

Comment: I haven't tested v3.0 myself, but I'm tempted to believe it works as advertised. ;) So I'm switching this to be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 44):

**NOTE:** These instructions are only relevant for Protractor versions older than v3.0. Protractor 3.0 includes built-in support for Browserstack.

---

### Prerequisites

You will need to have [node](http://nodejs.org/) and [npm](https://www.npmjs.org) installed. Check your node version with `node --version` to ensure it is greater than v0.10.0.

Ready?

### 1. Install Protractor

Use npm to install Protractor globally with:

```
npm install -g protractor
```

If you get errors, you might need to run the above command as sudo.

Here's a more detailed [tutorial for installing and using Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md).

### 2. Install Browserstack Selenium web driver

***EDIT:** @elgalu pointed out in the comments this step is not necessary. Apparently the BrowserStackLocal tunnel (set up in step 4) is enough.*

Following [Browserstack's instructions for setting up node.js](http://www.browserstack.com/automate/node), install the seleniun web driver:

```
npm install -g browserstack-webdriver
```

### 3. Set up Protractor configuration

Create a *protractor.conf.js* file (see documentation for [BrowserStack's supported capabilities](http://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities)):

```
exports.config = {
  capabilities: {
    'browserstack.user' : 'my_user_name',
    'browserstack.key' : 'my_secret_key',

    // Needed for testing localhost
    'browserstack.local' : 'true',

    // Settings for the browser you want to test
    // (check docs for difference between `browser` and `browserName`
    'browser' : 'Chrome',
    'browser_version' : '36.0',
    'os' : 'OS X',
    'os_version' : 'Mavericks',
    'resolution' : '1024x768'
  },

  // Browserstack's selenium server address
  seleniumAddress: 'http://hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub',

  // Pattern for finding test spec files
  specs: ['test/**/*.spec.js']
}
```

**Change your user name and secret key** to the ones given on the Browserstack Automate page. If you're logged in to Browserstack, the instructions for setting up node.js will have you user and key substituted in the examples, and you can just copy-paste the javascript from there.

The same page also has a tool for generating the code for different test browser settings.

### 4. Download and run BrowserStackLocal

Download the *BrowserStackLocal* binary from the [node.js instructions page](http://www.browserstack.com/automate/node#setting-local-tunnel).

Make the following changes to the command below, and run the binary to open the Browserstack tunnel required for testing.

- **Change your secret key** in the command. Again, *your_secret_key* will be automatically substituted in the node.js guide, if you're logged in to Browserstack.
- **Change the port number** to match the port you're hosting your AngularJS files at on localhost. The example uses port 3000.

  ```
  ./BrowserStackLocal your_secret_key localhost,3000,0
  ```

### 5. Run the tests

With everything ready for testing, run your tests:

```
protractor protractor.conf.js
```

You can watch the test run on [Browserstack Automate](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/) and even see an updating live screenshot of the test browser.

Comment: Are you sure you need `npm install -g browserstack-webdriver` ?

Comment: FYI I didn't need that: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1013#issuecomment-47714372

Comment: Good to know! I wasn't sure about it myself. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: In the config above, you use 'browser':'Chrome'. I had to change the setting to 'browserName':'Chrome' when using protractor 1.5.0.

Comment: @schwerwolf, I don't think that's dependent on protractor version. As far as I understand, the `capabilities` object is passed on to Browserstack's selenium server. They accept the following capabilities: http://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities

Answer (score 2):

**Hello!** To only run the test against Browserstack, you may need to skip *Step 4* from Niko Nyman answer, and in your *conf.js* you should have something like here's the one that I've used (+ report), then run *Step 5*:

---

```
    var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');
var reporter=new HtmlReporter({
    baseDirectory: './protractor-result', // a location to store screen shots.
    docTitle: 'Report Test Summary',
    docName:    'protractor-tests-report.html'
});

// An example configuration file.
exports.config = {
  // The address of a running selenium server.
  seleniumAddress: 'http://hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub',

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'version': '22.0',
    'browserstack.user' : 'user_name',
    'browserstack.key' : 'user_key',
    'browserstack.debug' : 'true'

  },

  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
  // protractor is called.
  specs: ['./specs/home_page_spec.js'],

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  },
 onPrepare: function() {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
      }

  };
```

Comment: This post reflects so well the reason I come each day on SO. I have so well explained my current problem and I'm happy. I have though one small question : how can I automatize my tests to run on multiple browsers. On the above examples on capabilities I see only one browser. How can I add like 5 browsers with 4 versions each ?

Answer (score 2):

We just wrote a blog post and open-source modules for this.

http://www.blog.wishtack.com/#!Cross-browser-testing-test-automation-with-Protractor-and-Browserstack/cuhk/554b3b5f0cf27313351f1163

wt-protractor-boilerplate
wt-protractor-runner
wt-protractor-utils