# browserstack connection issue

Tags: connection, protractor, browserstack

i created a test account to get started with browserStack. I followed the page here: [Running Protractor tests on Browserstack Automate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537919/running-protractor-tests-on-browserstack-automate) which was really helpful.

But when starting my Test i get this:

```
[09:32:46] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub
[09:32:46] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[09:32:47] E/launcher - Error code: 135
[09:32:47] E/launcher - Error message: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 104.20.3.155:80
[09:32:47] E/launcher - Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 104.20.3.155:80
```

Update!

Then i added:
'webDriverProxy': 'https://proxy.myerver.de:1234',

Now i get:

```
[10:35:04] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at https://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub
[10:35:04] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[10:35:04] E/launcher - EPROTO write EPROTO
[10:35:04] E/launcher - Error: EPROTO write EPROTO
```

What does this mean? i do not any requests. i just open a page, click on an element and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Node Tunnel](https://github.com/koichik/node-tunnel) module to specify the proxy details. You can override all https request to use proxy like below:

```
var tunnel = require('tunnel'), https = require('https');

var tunnelingAgent = tunnel.httpsOverHttps({
  proxy: {
    host: 'proxy.myerver.de',
    port: 1234
  }
});

var oldRequest = https.request;
https.request = function(options){
    options.agent = tunnelingAgent;
    return oldRequest(options);
}
```

Warning: Untested code :)